# Does there exist a polynomial $f(x, y, z)$ which is positive iff |x|, |y|, |z| are sides of a triangle?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, contest-math, polyhedra

The following problem appeared in the Kömal (Hungarian mathematical journal) in year 1997. Official Source: [Problem N 145](https://www.komal.hu/verseny/1997-09/mat.e.shtml) at the end of the page here.

**Problem.** Does there exist a polynomial $f(x, y, z)$ of real coefficients such that $f(x,y,z)$ is positive if and only if $|x|, |y|, |z|$ are sides of a triangle?

The given inequalities $|x|+|y|>|z|$, $|y|+|z|>|x|$, and $|x|+|z|>|y|$ impose an interesting geometric region in $\mathbb{R}^3$:

[image]

I am guessing that the question has a negative answer -- no such polynomial should exist. Any thoughts / comments / hints are appreciated!

Comment: It shouldn't exist. Letting one of the variables grow arbitrary big, should  make the function negative. One can find positive values in the area where x,y,z are close for arbitrary big x,y,z. I think one should be able to proof that functions that go to $-\infty$ if one of the variables goes to $\pm\infty$ have a finite square/ball where its values are non-negative. This is just a lot of hand wavy intuïtion, so it might be wrong, but that's my guess on how to disprove this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that either all $|x|+|y|-|z|$, $|y|+|z|-|x|$, and $|z|+|x|-|y|$ are positive or just one of them is negative. Hence,

$$(|x|+|y|-|z|)(|y|+|z|-|x|)(|z|+|x|-|y|)>0 \iff |x|,|y|,|z|   \text{ are  sides of a triangle.}$$

So, $f^*(x,y,z)=(|x|+|y|-|z|)(|y|+|z|-|x|)(|z|+|x|-|y|)$ can work as a source for generating a desired function. As @Macavity suggested in the comments, we have:

$$f(x,y,z)=(|x|+|y|-|z|)(|y|+|z|-|x|)(|z|+|x|-|y|)(|x|+|y|+|z|) \\=2x^2y^2+2x^2z^2+2y^2z^2-x^4-y^4-z^4.$$

Thus, such a polynomial exists as shown above.

---

**PS:** It seems that the OP has been indirectly answered at [this link.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827304/need-algebra-tip-about-a4-b4-c4-2b2c2-2a2b2-2a2c2-for-sides?noredirect=1)